# Debug Error in MySQL syntax please

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

Any ideas what I am doing wrong???

```
INSERT INTO LondonFixes ('id', 'Metal', 'AmPm', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR', 'Updated')VALUES(NULL, 'Gold', 'AM', '1055.91', '1646.00', '1272.03', '2012-06-19')
```

gives the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id', 'Metal', 'AmPm', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR', 'Updated')VALUES(NULL, 'Gold', 'AM',' at line 1
```

Comment: you dont put quotes around the field names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO LondonFixes (id, Meta, AmPm, GBP, USD, EUR, Updated)
 VALUES(NULL, 'Gold', 'AM', '1055.91', '1646.00', '1272.03', '2012-06-19')
```

Comment: thank you. I had one error, tested a query in phpmyadmin, and it put backticks in there. I thought these were same as single quotes!!!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, if you want to escape the column names, do not use `single quote` but instead use `backtick`.

```
INSERT INTO LondonFixes (`id`, `Metal`, `AmPm`, `GBP`, `USD`, `EUR`, `Updated`)
VALUES(NULL, 'Gold', 'AM', '1055.91', '1646.00', '1272.03', '2012-06-19')
```

Comment: Thanks, whats the difference between backtick vs single quote?

Comment: single quotes wraps a value while backtick escapes column name from reserved keywords.